# Assign new a variable to a value in R

Tags: r

Using R, I need to assign variable `a`, `b`...whenever a new value is returned. For example if value is between 1:5 assign it `a`, if it's between 6:7 assign it `b`. Here is my r code:

```
hg1<- ifelse((hg >= 1) & (hg <= 5), "D", 
         ifelse(hg = 6), "C", 
         ifelse((hg >= 7) & (hg <= 8),"B"), 
         ifelse((hg >= 9) & (hg <= 12),"A")
         )
```

Comment: You can use `cut` for this `cut(hg, breaks=c(1,5,6,7,8, 9, 12))` and specify the `labels` as an argument

Comment: @akrun I would like to write the assigned variable in a table e.g hg=A

Comment: I am not sure I understand it.  You may split the `hg` by the `cut` grouping vector and the output list elements can be named with the letters as you showed and then use `list2env` if you need multiple objects in the global enviornment.

Comment: the cut function creates this Levels: (1,5] (5,6] (6,7] (7,8] (8,9] (9,12], I however need 4 levels i.e. 1:5, 6, 7:8, 9:12

Comment: I posted a solution below.  Please check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we need to create some objects in the global environment based on the values in a vector ('hg').  Based on the description, values ranging from 1 to 5 would be assigned to 'D', 6 as 'C', 7 to 8 would be 'B' and 9 to 12 as 'A'.  If there is any value outside the range, it will be classified as 'Other'

Here, I `cbind` the logical vectors created from multiple comparison and do the `%*%` with sequence of 4 ie. the total number of comparison to get unique numeric index.  Based on the index, we can change the group to the `LETTER` group.

```
 v1 <- c( cbind(hg %in% 1:5, hg==6, hg %in% 7:8, hg %in% 9:12) %*% seq_len(4) +1)
```

`split` the original vector with that grouping index so that the list elements will be named with the grouping index.

```
 lst <- split(hg, c('Other', LETTERS[4:1])[v1])
```

It can be used to create objects in the global environment with `list2env` (not recommended though).

```
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
 D
 #[1] 4 3 4 3 5 4 2 2
 A
 #[1] 10  9 11 12  9 10 10

 B
 #[1] 7 7
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 hg <- sample(0:14, 20, replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely.

Do you want to assign `hg` to new variables `a` or `b`, in which case:

```
assign(ifelse(hg %in% 1:5, "a", "b"), hg)
```

Or do you want to assign characters `"a"` or `"b"` to `hg1`, in which case:

```
hg1 <- ifelse(hg %in% 1:5, "a", "b")
```

This code assumes that hg is 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7.  If it could be otherwise, you will need to develop it a bit more.

An alternative, based on the comment:

```
hg_op <- c(rep("a", 5), "b", rep("c", 2), rep("d", 4)) #once at beginning
hg1 <- hg_op[hg] #as many times as you need
```

Comment: My data is such that I have a variable hg which can be between 1:12. I would want assign character a, b, c or d if the values fall between 1:5, 6, 7:8 or 9: 12 respectively. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: your solutions works, could you please explain the first part which generates hg_op

Comment: `hg_op` is a vector.  The second line just selects the appropriate value of the vector.  Conveniently, in your case, `hg` can take integer values from 1 to another positive integer, so you can just use the index numbers to select what you want.  `c` is the concatenate function, which creates vectors.  It can also bind vectors together (e.g. `rep("a", 5)`) into one long vector.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but in the second line, it should be
`ifelse(hg == 6), "C",`
to check that `hg` has value `6` or not.

Comment: the code should check the value in hg, if its 4 for example then it assigns hg1 the variable D

Comment: SN248 means that your code has the wrong notation.  Does it do what you expect when you correct that?  Put `==` instead of `=`.